# How to fetch data from non public API site like instagram which don't have json response [Javascript]?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch information like the number of posts, followers, following, bio from Instagram profile URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use web-scraping method to **scrape** data of different profiles, for js you can use puppeteer or selenium-webdriver-js.

Note : if there is APIs available than go for APIs. APIs >> Scraping

Comment: I will definitely try it

Answer (score 0):

It's not public API you have to log in first, get desired cookies then call Instagram APIs.

There is a package in npm which makes it much easier to communicate with Instagram APIs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tools-for-instagram

It has all neccsasery APIs.

Just keep in mind that they have strict rate limit rules so always set delays between multiple requests (i.e 5-second delay when you are forwarding 100 accounts)